# What permissions are essential for executing a script by entering its name?

Tags: linux, permissions

I am working on permissions in Linux. I am not sure if I also need `r` and `w` permissions if I want to execute a file.

Comment: You only need `x` (execute)

Answer (score 2):

You need only the `x` (execute) permission to execute a file.

Depending on your need, you can set the `x` permission to:

- the owner only (`chmod u+x file`)
- the group (`chmod g+x file`)
- everyone else (`chmod o+x file`)
- all of the above (`chmod +x file`)

Comment: That being said, a script with `#!` line will also need `r` so the interpreter can read the file, at least in my very cursory test with a bash script.